Variability of patients in different Hospitals
just to let you know that my statistical background is not very good. I made funnel graphs which shows the effect of polypharmacy against practice size.

In the funnel graphs, a dot presents a single practice and I have total 115 practices.   There was a lot of variability in the funnel graphs because the level of polypharmacy is either going too high or too low from the mean and going out from the upper and lower confidence interval. This is because there is too much variability in the level of polypharmacy by practice population. I further fixed the funnel graphs by age groups and  then analyzed the graphs and concluded that the variability was because polypharmacy was more driven by younger age group as compared to old age group. Younger age group was not closed to mean whereas the practices by old age group were within confidence intervals. Now I want to find how I am going to check the variability of polypharmacy by practice size. I used Generalized liner mixed effect model and later used predict function to calculate the  Standard Incident Ratio to see the variability between expected and observed polypharmacy patients by practice but the difference is very small. I am looking to find more advanced graphical or statistical method to analyze this variability. what could be that one please. thanks
